# Codeigniter not sending email with smtp settings

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the email.php in config folder:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'tls',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.lifepro.ro',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'office@lifepro.ro',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

and this function in helper

```
    function email_send($to, $subject, $body) {

        $ci = get_instance();
        $ci->email->from('office@lifepro.ro', 'Office LifePro');
        $ci->email->to($to);
        $ci->email->cc('office@lifepro.ro');

        $ci->email->subject($subject);
        $ci->email->message($body);

        if($ci->email->send())
            return true;
    }
```

The problem is that the CI is sending the email even if I type wrong credentials. Why is happening this? I know email.php from config folder is loaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you have to do in E-mail library, Use this

```
$this->load->library('email'); //load library 

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

if(!$this->email->send())
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
else
{
    echo "Sent"
}
```

[Email Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
'protocol' => 'smtp'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls', //         <--- notice
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.lifepro.ro',
    'smtp_port' => 465, //             <--- or 587
    'smtp_user' => 'office@lifepro.ro',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```